# How to construct this query in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table:

```
Date        ColumnA    ColumnB
2009-12-29    "abc"     "abc"
2009-12-29    "abc"     "abc"
2009-12-29    "abc"     "abc"
2009-12-28    "abc"     "abc"
2009-12-28    "abc"     "abc"
2009-12-28    "abc"     "abc"
,,,
,,,
```

I want to write a query, in Microsoft SQL, that returns all rows for the latest available date in the table. So in the above case, it returns all rows with date 12-12-29.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT Date, ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM TableName 
WHERE Date = 
  (SELECT max(Date) FROM TableName)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        date DESC
```

This will work even for composite maximums (like, `(date, othercolumn)`, which cannot be retrieved with a plain `MAX`)

You may want to read these articles in my blog for several ways to do this:

- [**SQL Server: Selecting records holding group-wise maximum**](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/30/sql-server-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum/)
- [**SQL Server: Selecting records holding group-wise maximum (with ties)**](http://explainextended.com/2009/12/01/sql-server-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum-with-ties/)